# Can my project's Web.config manually inherit from another Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

## My Setting

I'm creating a base mvc project for a number of other mvc projects where all the error handling and basic user validation is located so that I don't have to duplicate the boilerplate code in all of the other projects. With the help of my favorite dependency injection container (go, go [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/)) I was able to put my `ErrorController` within the base project and have it being used by the other projects. The same goes for the custom user validation attribute I created.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 targetting .NET4.0 with the following layout:

```
MvcBase
+- Controllers
 +- ErrorController.cs // Common error controller
+- Filters
 +- AuthenticateUserAttribute.cs
+- Application.cs // Base class for all MVC applications
+- Web.config // Base configuration (*)

MvcProject1
+- Views
 +- Error
  +- Index.cshtml
+- Web.config

MvcProject2
+- Views
 +- Error
  +- Index.cshtml
+- Web.config
```

## The Question

I know that the `Web.config`s inherit from parent directories but is there a way to explicitly state the base config file such a configuration should inherit from? In my case it would be great to be able to reference the (*) `Web.config`, which is located at the same hierarchical level as the projects containing the other `Web.config`s. My use case is that I want to store some information in the basic `Web.config` that is the same in all other projects (e.g. configuration for error emails) that I don't want to duplicate in the other projects to keep the overall architecture as [DRY](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) as possible.

Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of achieve what you're looking for via the `configSource` attribute. You add that attribute to a section of your web.config with a path to another config file that holds those settings, e.g.:

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings configSource="bin/ConnectionStrings.config"></connectionStrings>
```

**ConnectionStrings.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add ... />
</connectionsStrings>
```

Then, you can use the `Add... > Existing File" option to add these configs to other projects. After you select the config file you want to add, click the arrow next to the "Add" button and choose "Add Link" instead. This will cause Visual Studio to simply create a link to the existing file instead of copying it into the project. Then, any changes will propogate automatically to any project that has linked to the file.

Comment: That's close to the idea I had, albeit it's not exactly what I wanted I will mark it as the accepted answer for now, thanks!